# WUT-121 This file transfer has been forbidden by the Administrator

Tags: java, oracle, applet, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am a user of an Oracle Forms software, and when I try to import a file from my PC to the software, I get the error: `WUT-121 This file transfer has been forbidden by the Administrator`.

After some research, I found out that I should update a `webutil.cfg` file. But I don't have this file (I am not a developer but and end user).

Some of my colleagues can import the file successfully. So I thought this is a problem related to my PC. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to be granted for directory permissions by your system Administrator.

On the other hand, perhaps you can try to transfer some `.ddl` files such as `jacob.dll`, `JNIsharedstubs.dll`, and `d2kwut60.dll` to your  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin`

( as being your `Current Version` for `Java Runtime Environment`(`JRE`) assuming you have JRE version `8u211` ) to be able to run `webutil` utility of forms if it's the case. To manage such a transfer, editing `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_211\lib\security\java.policy` file as adding

```
grant {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

part to the bottom of the file.